# Сортировка данных из mysql

Tags: php, mysql, сортировка

Я учусь, поэтому вопрос может показаться глупым ))
Есть скрипт, который выводит из базы mysql данные, все работает, только есть один момент - рабочая смена с 9:00 утра до 9:00 следующего дня, мне нужно чтобы записи с ночи следующего дня, до 9:00 попадали в предыдущий день. На картинке все должно быть понятно, т.е. записи из 31 числа, должны были попасть в 30, т.к. они были сделаны до 09:00 утра... Подскажите как можно реализовать!? Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
if ($_POST["go"]) {//Обработка формы по нажатию кнопки
$start_date = $get_year1."-".$get_mounf1."-".$get_day1." ".$get_hour1.":".$get_min1;
$stop_date = $get_year2."-".$get_mounf2."-".$get_day2." ".$get_hour2.":".$get_min2;}

if ($_GET[start_date] AND $_GET[stop_date]) {//обработка формы из вне, заменяем предыдущие значения переменной
$start_date = $_GET[start_date]." ".$_GET[start_time];
$stop_date = $_GET[stop_date]." ".$_GET[stop_time];}

print $start_date." -- ".$stop_date."<br>"; //проверочная строка

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM history WHERE start_work BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$stop_date' ORDER BY  `history`.`start_work` DESC");


?><table class="bordered"><tr>
<th width="71"><div align="center"><b><i>Дата</i></b></div></th>
<th width="74"><div align="center"><b><i>Время</i></b></div></th>
<th width="212"><b><i>Услуга</b></th>
<th width="82"><div align="center"><b><i>Стоимость</i></b></div></th>
<th width="135"><div align="center"><b><i>Со скидкой</i></b></div></th>
<th width="276"><b><i>Примечание</i></b></th>
</tr><?


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 


$sale = $row[sale];
$note = $row[note];
$row_id = $row[id];

$str_start_work = $row[start_work];
$arr_start_work = explode(" ", $str_start_work); //разбиваем строку start_work на дату и время
$start_work_date = $arr_start_work[0]; //получаем дату
$start_work_time = $arr_start_work[1]; //получаем время

$arr_date = explode("-", $start_work_date);
$year_date = $arr_date[0]; //год
$mounf_date = $arr_date[1]; //месяц
$day_date = $arr_date[2]; //день

$arr_time = explode(":", $start_work_time);
$h_time = $arr_time[0]; //часы
$m_time = $arr_time[1]; //минуты


//---------------------- выводим заголовки ------------------------------ //
if (!$m_title OR $m_title != $mounf_date){
?><tr><td colspan="6"><div align="center"><b><?=$mounf_name[str_replace('0', '', $mounf_date)]." ".$year_date;?></b>
[<a href="visual.php?date=<?=$mounf_date."-".$year_date;?>" 
onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'scrollbars=1,height='+Math.min(400, screen.availHeight)+',width='+Math.min(525, screen.availWidth)); return false;">сводная таблица</a>]</div></tr><?
}

if (!$m_day OR $m_day != $day_date){
?><tr><td colspan="6"><div align="center"><b><?=$day_date."/".$mounf_date."/".$year_date;?></b>
[<a href="visual.php?day=<?=$day_date;?>&date=<?=$mounf_date."-".$year_date;?>" 
onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'scrollbars=1,height='+Math.min(400, screen.availHeight)+',width='+Math.min(525, screen.availWidth)); return false;">сводная таблица</a>]</div></tr><?
}



//---------------------- !выводим заголовки ------------------------------ //



//---------------------- выводим строчки ------------------------------ //
?>

<td width="71"><div align="center"><?=$day_date."/".$mounf_date."/".$year_date;?></div></td>
<td width="74"><div align="center"><?=$h_time.":".$m_time;?></div></td>
<td width="212"><?

$row = explode("/", $row['type']);
$i_pp=1;
foreach($row as $t_row){
if ($i_pp == '1'){ $t_price='0'; }
list($u_name, $u_cat, $u_price) = explode(":", $t_row); //получаем сумму
if ($u_name){
print "<nobr>".$i_pp.". ".$u_name." (кат. ".$u_cat.")</nobr><br>";
}//if
$i_pp++;

$t_price = $u_price+$t_price;
}//for


?></th>
<td width="82"><div align="center"><?=number_format($t_price, 0, ',', ' ');?>р.</div></td>
<td width="135"><div align="center"><?

if ($sale){
print number_format($t_price-($t_price/100*$sale), 0, ',', ' ')."р.";
}else{
print "нет скидки";
}
?></div></td>
<td width="276">
<a style='text-decoration: none; float:left;' href="note.php?id=<?=$row_id;?>" onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'scrollbars=1,height='+Math.min(400, screen.availHeight)+',width='+Math.min(525, screen.availWidth)); return false;"><font color='green'>&#9998;</font></a>
<?=$note;?></td>
</tr>


<?
//---------------------- выводим строчки ------------------------------ //

$m_title = $mounf_date;
$m_day = $day_date;


}//while
```

Comment: Вычтите из даты 9 часов. (`date - interval 9 hour`)

Comment: к сожалению, пока мне это мало о чем говорит ((

Comment: В секции WHERE запроса нужно к значениям $start_date и $stop_date прибавить те самые 9 часов.

Comment: Если вы не разделите HTML и PHP код в разные файлы, разобраться потом будет очень сложно, времени будет тратиться очень много, особенно, если познания в языках очень малы.